# Using class weights with lmer

Tags: r, lme4, weighted

I am running a linear mixed effect model using lme4 with a continuous variable (“Ratio” of young to old trees by species) by two interacting categorical variables (“Disperser” and “Site”), and one random effect (“Species”).

I want to use case weights to account for the fact that some species are more common than others, so I have used a numerical vector where higher numbers equate to a higher density of adult trees (“Weight”). Although the model returns a mostly logical output, I am getting AIC, BIC and deviance of ‘infinity’, and log likelihood of ‘- infinity’ when I add the weights argument.

```
library(lme4)
my_data <- data.frame(Species = sample(LETTERS, size=52, replace=TRUE), 
                  Site = sample(c("Site_A", "Site_B"), size=52, replace=TRUE),
                  Ratio = sample(0:10, size=52, replace=TRUE), 
                  Disperser = sample(c("Mouse", "Bird", "Bat", "Wind"), size=52, replace=TRUE),
                  Weight = sample(0:5, size=52, replace=TRUE)
                  )

model <- lmer(Ratio ~ Disperser * Site + (1|Species), weights=Weight, data=my_data, REML=FALSE)

summary(model)

Linear mixed model fit by maximum likelihood  ['lmerMod']
Formula: Ratio ~ Disperser * Site + (1 | Species)
Data: my_data
Weights: Weight

 AIC      BIC   logLik deviance df.resid 
 Inf      Inf     -Inf      Inf       42
```

Can anyone tell me why I might be getting this output? Is this a fundamental problem with the data I am trying to fit to the model or an error in the use of the 'weights' argument?

Comment: What is a weight of 0 supposed to do?  Are these values you'd like to remove from your dataset all together?  Notice the subtle message `Gradient contains NAs` at the bottom of the `summary` output.  This and the `Inf` go away if you use positive, non-zero weights.

Comment: Thank you aosmith, the model ran fine when I removed the zeros, I expected that if I ran a weight of 0 then the data point would be removed but I can do this effectively by removing the 0's myself.